# ADFS 2.0 custom login page implementation - "The request scope is not valid or is not supported"

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, active-directory, adfs2.0, adfs

I am trying to work out how to set up my SharePoint 2013 to use a custom login page to login through ADFS 2.0 instead of the standard one. 
I am following this tutorial: http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=76

After making the changes to web.config I have written the following code to my page:

```
using (var wsFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), new EndpointAddress(endpoint)))
{
    wsFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = signInControl.UserName;
    wsFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = signInControl.Password;

    wsFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

    var wsChannel = wsFactory.CreateChannel();

    var requestSecurityToken = new RequestSecurityToken { RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue, AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(AppliesToEndpointUrl), KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric };

    try
    {
        var genericSecurityToken = wsChannel.Issue(requestSecurityToken) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;

        var securityTokenHandlers = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

        var securityToken = securityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericSecurityToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken));

        var rUrl = Request.QueryString.Get("Source");

        Response.Redirect(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rUrl) ? "~/Pages/Default.aspx" : rUrl);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

The debugger throws the following error on the wsChannel.Issue method invocation:

> ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported.

Now, how should I investigate the cause of such error?